# Is there anything wrong with referencing an instance variable without implementing a getter?

Tags: python, class

In a nutshell, I receive json events via an API and recently I've been learning a lot more about classes. One of the recommended ways to use classes is to implement getters, setters etc.. However, my classes aren't too sophisticated all they're doing is parsing data from a json object and passing better formatted data onto further ETL processes.

Below is a simple example of what I've encountered.

```
data = {'status': 'ready'}


class StatusHandler:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.status = data.get('status', None)


class StatusHandler2:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._status = data.get('status', None)

    @property
    def status(self):
        return self._status


without_getter = StatusHandler(data)
print(without_getter.status)

with_getter = StatusHandler2(data)
print(with_getter.status)
```

Is there anything wrong with me using the class StatusHandler and referencing a status instance variable and using that to pass information forward to other bits of code? I'm just wondering if further down the line as my project gets more complicated that this would be an issue as it doesn't seem to be standard although I could be wrong...

Comment: "One of the recommended ways to use classes is to implement getters, setters etc.." no, not in Python. The **entire point** of `property` is to not have to write boilerplate getters and setters. Unless your getters and setters actually do something **don't make a property** Not sure what code you are reading, but check out the python standard library and you never see pointless getters and setters. That is not the python way. This is not Java.

Comment: getters and setters are relevant if you want to perform some additional logic. E.g. checking if the set value is a valid value (has to be a number, in a certain range, etc.) It can also be relevant if you want to log the information. But if you don't care you are fine addressing them directly.

Comment: @TinNguyen explicit getters/setters are still irrelevant in Python - we do have computed attributes for this.

Comment: Note, the two classes are not equivalent. In the second case, the attribute is not settable. That is a valid use-case for defining a simple `property` that just returns `self._some_var`, but if that isn't what you intend, go with the first version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of getters/setters is to avoid replacing plain attributes access with computed ones without breaking client code if and when you have to change your implementation. This only make sense for languages that have no support for computed attributes.

Python **has** a quite strong support for computed attributes thru [the descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), including the generic builtin `property` type, so you don't need explicit getters/setters - if you have to change your implementation, just replace affected public attributes by computed ones.

Just make sure to not abuse computed attributes - they should not make any heavy computation, external resource access or so. No one expects what looks like an attribute to have a high cost or raise IOErrors or so ;-)

**EDIT**

With regard to your example: computed attributes are a way to control attribute access, and making an attribute read-only (not providing a setter for your `property`) IS a perfectly valid use case - IF you have a reason to make it read-only of course.